# NameError: name 'sca' is not defined in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

The following code is about linear classification in scikit-learn using iris dataset. It is from the book by Garreta, Moncecchi. However, it throws an error "NameError: name 'sca' is not defined". What's possibly wrong ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_iris,y_iris = iris.data, iris.target
X,y = X_iris[:,:2], y_iris
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state = 33)

clf = SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
print clf.coef_
print clf.intercept_
x_min, x_max = X_train[:,0].min()-0.5,X_train[:,0].max()+0.5
y_min, y_max = X_train[:,1].min()-0.5,X_train[:,1].max()+0.5
xs = np.arange(x_min,x_max,0.5)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
fig.set_size_inches(10,6)
for i in [0,1,2]:
    axes[i].set_aspect('equal')
    axes[i].set_title('Class '+ str(i) + ' versus the rest')
    axes[i].set_xlabel('Sepal length')
    axes[i].set_ylabel('Sepal width')
    axes[i].set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
    axes[i].set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
    sca(axes[i])
    plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train,cmap=plt.cm.prism)
    ys = (-clf.intercept_[i] - xs * clf.coef_[i, 0]) / clf.coef_[i, 1]
    plt.plot(xs, ys, hold=True)

plt.show()
```

When the line is commented out, two of the subplots are not showing any image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line which calls sca with plt.sca. I noticed that sca is matplotlib.pyplot function and called without its alias.

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.sca.html